# ¿Cómo funcionan las rutas en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

A modo de curiosidad tengo la siguiente duda.

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Me llama la atención la sintaxis ya que normalmente eso lo haría así.

```
$Route->get('/', function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

¿Como es posible esa sintaxis de Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que `Route` es una *Facade* que ayuda a simplificar el acceso a los métodos de dicha clase.

Por lo tanto es incorrecto que trates dicha fachada como una variable cuando de hecho no lo es.

`get` por otro lado es un método correspondiente a la clase **`Router`** que puedes leer su ubicación en la anotación siguiente:

```
@see \Illuminate\Routing\Router
```

Y con una sintaxis como puedes apreciar en el siguiente script

```
//vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route.php
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'router';
}
```

Podemos ser mas exactos al respecto del método **`getFacadeAccessor`** si leemos la propia documentación y cito<sup>1</sup>

> [...] This method's job is to return the name of a service container binding [...].

Que se puede traducir como:

> El trabajo de este método es devolver el nombre de un enlace del contenedor de servicios.

**Comentario**

- Cabe entonces mencionar que el patrón de diseño estructural `Facade` no nace con Laravel, pero si que lo implementa dentro de la estructura de muchas de sus clases.

  - Aunque te darás cuenta (*como me pasó a mi*) que va mas allá de sólo pensar en invocar métodos estáticos
- Esto es solo **un un pequeño acercamiento** del tema, pero claramente debes profundizar en el.
- Te recomiendo leer mas sobre el *Service Container*
- Si requieres conocer más Facades que tiene Laravel, este namespace te indica así mismo la ruta donde *viven*.

  ```
    Illuminate\Support\Facades
  ```

No son los únicos pero recomiendo leas a detalle los siguientes recursos del framework:

- La clase abstracta *Facade* ubicada en **`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`**
- Así como la interfaz *Application* que extiende de la clase *Container* unicada en **`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application`**

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[How facades work?](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#how-facades-work)
- [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container)
- [Laravel Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#introduction)

Comment: O sea, que Route es método? no un objeto? Estoy sorprendido. Desconocía sobre eso.

Comment: En unos minutos te amplio la respuesta

Comment: Pero como es posible que use Route sin el $ a eso me refiero, o sea, pensaba que era una constante, todo mi conocimiento de PHP se ha vuelto loco ahora.

Comment: Route es el nombre de una de las clases de Laravel, te recomiendo indagar en la ruta que te menciono en la respuesta, a medida que vayas revisando el contenido irás comprendiendo mejor de lo que va

Comment: Pero si es una clase como es que puede escribirse Route sin el $

Comment: Por que el símbolo de `$` solo se usa para declarar variables, no constantes y menos nombres de clases @GabrielZapata

Comment: Pero cuando declaro una clase por ejemplo `class Route {...}` si la quiero usar hago lo siguiente `$route = new Route` y si dentro de `class Route` tengo una función por ejemplo `public function get(){..}` y luego quiero usarla tendría que hacer esto `$route->get()` como es que laravel hace esto `Route::get()` como es que no usa el `$` eso es lo que me confunde.

Comment: ¿Entonces como debería declarar mis funciones para que pueda hacer esa sintaxis?

Answer (score 1):

En realidad eso no es parte de una sintaxis propia de Laravel, sino de PHP.

En PHP, para acceder a un método estático, ha de utilizarse el [operador de resolución de ámbito](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) , tal y como se hace, por ejemplo, en el archivo routes.